# "EventTarget is not defined" error in angular ssr environment variable on build

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-universal

angular-cli.json

```
 "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
    "staging": "environments/environment.staging.ts"
  }
},
```

Environment Files

environment/environment.ts

environment/environment.prod.ts

environment/environment.staging.ts

command 
ng build --env=staging

Comment: Do you use EventTarget interface in your code?

Comment: No i'm not using that kind of interface

Comment: Is it a runtime or compile time error?

Comment: I'm using that in a directive and when compile angular 9 build that error arise... the code is something like:

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public onClick(target: EventTarget) {